# Output of a function in R with a list (lda model, ggplot, dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, function, ggplot2, linear-discriminant

I am struggling on how to get an output of a function in R I am creating with a list of elements. Apparently it is simple, however, I cannot get into that. I checked different questions in SO but no result. This might be an easy question and probably I am misprinting some line.

The output of the function I am creating has three elements that I think they should be included in a list:

- Linear discriminant analysis model (lda).
- A dataframe
- A ggplot image

This is the version of the function I am working with:

```
fun <- function(data, tooth_type = c("m1", "m2", "m3"), position = c("U", "L")) {
  model <- lda(Species ~ MD + BL, data = data) 
  # extract the information of the tooth we are working from the Omo database
  tooth <- omo_numeric_mdbl[omo_numeric_mdbl$Tooth == tooth_type & omo_numeric_mdbl$Position == position, ]
  tooth <- tooth[complete.cases(tooth[, 31:32]), ]
  predictions <- model %>%
    predict(tooth)
  pred <- as.data.frame(predictions$posterior)*100
  # plot
  lda.data <- cbind(data, predict(model)$x)
  ggplot_fun <- ggplot(lda.data, aes(LD1, LD2)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Species))
  list(model, pred, ggplot_fun)
}
```

As you can see, inside the function there are three objects I would like to store:

- `pred`: this is the dataframe
- `model`: this is the lda information
- `ggplot_fun`: this is the ggplot image

I tried:

- `as.list(model, pred, ggplot_fun)` -> unsuccessful
- `list(model, pred, ggplot_fun)` -> unsuccessful
- `x <- as.list(model, pred, ggplot_fun); return(x)` -> unsuccessful
- `x <- list(model, pred, ggplot_fun); return(x)` -> unsuccessful

Ultimately, what I would like is:

```
x <- fun(data, "m3", "L") # for example

x$pred       # show the dataframe (and display as kable, if required)
x$model      # show the lda model, and to get all the details inside as x$model$posterior
x$ggplot_fun # display the ggplot function
```

Comment: And what output are you getting at the moment? We don't have any data that would work on your function to test it, and you didn't tell us what your function is currently outputing. Are you getting an error? A warning? No output?

Comment: I was having an output, but everything was messy. I found out the solution and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. In order to give the answer to others with the same questions I changed the last line of the example:

```
list(model, pred, ggplot_fun)
```

By this one

```
list(LDA = model, Prediction = pred, Ggplot = ggplot_fun)
```

Basically I named each of the elements.